# Stuck on keyboard layout

Tags: raspbian, noobs

I have a Logitech combo mk345 wireless mouse and keyboard (Y-R0042).

When I press <kbd>#</kbd> the pound sign is printed on screen

Have tried the `sudo raspi config` > change keyboard (no success) probably messed that up since I started with Pi 2 days ago.

Then the `sudo nano .....keyboard...` changed `gb` to `us` and `sudo reboot`.

But after reboot there was no change and the `us` in keyboard default changed back to `gb`.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange network! If you haven't guessed the Raspberry Pi is a __British__ designed product and so the defaults are set for us "Whingeing Poms" as those exiled to the Australian continent have been known to call us! 8-)  I'm not sure if any of the things mentioned over on the SU branch [how-to-change-input-keyboard-layout-while-in-console](http://superuser.com/questions/404457/how-to-change-input-keyboard-layout-while-in-console#404507) has any relevance as, by the sound of it you could be in a GUI...

Comment: Have you tried changing the locale itself? This happened to me before and, to be honest, I forgot how I fixed it.

Comment: Did you save the changes when you used nano to change GB to US?